# how to get the filter count of the row by selecting Drop down of ng-table

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ngtable

Kindly check on the below link. I am trying to get the count of the row which is selected from the drop down menu of the table.

Click the search icon to get the option.

```
<div ng-controller="selectFilterController">

    <table id="countTable" ng-table="tableParams" class="table" show-filter="showFilter">
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="row in $data">
                <td data-title="'Suite Name'" filter="{suiteId: 'select'}" filter-data="suiteId" sortable="'suiteId'">{{ row.suiteId }}</td>
                <td data-title="'TestRunID#'" filter="{testRunId: 'text'}" sortable="'testRunId'">{{ row.testRunId}}</td>
                <td data-title="'TestCase#'" filter="{testCaseNumber: 'text'}" sortable="'testCaseNumber'">{{ row.testCaseNumber }}</td>
                <td data-title="'AutoPolicy#'" filter="{autoPolicyNumber: 'text'}" sortable="'autoPolicyNumber'">{{ row.autoPolicyNumber }}</td>
                <td data-title="'Result'" filter="{testResult: 'text'}" sortable="'testResult'">{{ row.testResult }}</td>
                <td>
                    <button type="button" data-ng-click="showDetails(row.testCaseNumber);" class="btn w3-green w3-hover-blue">View</button>
                </td>

            </tr>

        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Here is my [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/WKGBl2U8SW5Sul8FDfYD?p=preview)

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/WKGBl2U8SW5Sul8FDfYD?p=preview

Comment: Kindly check the above link

Comment: what exactly do you want? the total of row with all filter?

Comment: @FetraR. Yes!                            .

Comment: so check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According the doc: http://ng-table.com/api-docs/classes/ngtableparams.html

> **Methods > total**
>
> total(): number total(total: number) Defined in
>   src/core/ngTableParams.ts:522 Returns the count of the data rows that
>   match the current filter

so in your case, you can get it in your html by:

```
Total row is: {{tableParams.total()}}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help  :)